# How to make this glassy/pluck sound

Tags: sound-design

Im pretty sure this is made with sylenth or massive, but how?

From 1:38 to 2:00
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It could be an additive synth using the timbre of a bell to define its harmonics...layer oscillators in different pitch relationships to each other or layer multiple synths.  FM synthesis is often used to generate bell-like sounds too, which have a naturally computerized sound.  And lastly you can load in a field recording of a small bell into a sampler and use it as one of your layers, combine it with some gently futzed sinewaves and you've got yourself an instrument.

There is a heavy pitch glide/portamento as well, and it sounds like at points they've taken a note, reversed it, and added it to right before the beginning of the next note to give that pull and push feel.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have logic? If so, try sculpture, it's a modelling synth of a string, great for making these kinds of sounds